# Get the current + the next word in a string

Tags: php, string

this is what I try to get:
`My longest text to test` When I search for e.g. `My` I should get `My longest`

I tried it with this function to get first the complete length of the input and then I search for the ' ' to cut it.

`$length = strripos($text, $input) + strlen($input)+2;`

`$stringpos = strripos($text, ' ', $length);`

`$newstring = substr($text, 0, strpos($text, ' ', $length));`

But this only works first time and then it cuts after the current input, means 
`My lon` is `My longest` and not `My longest text`.

How I must change this to get the right result, always getting the next word. Maybe I need a break, but I cannot find the right solution.

**UPDATE**

Here is my workaround till I find a better solution. As I said working with array functions does not work, since part words should work. So I extended my previous idea a bit. Basic idea is to differ between first time and the next. I improved the code a bit.

```
function  get_title($input, $text) {
    $length       = strripos($text, $input) + strlen($input);   
$stringpos = stripos($text, ' ', $length);
// Find next ' '
$stringpos2 = stripos($text, ' ', $stringpos+1);

if (!$stringpos) {
    $newstring = $text;
} else if ($stringpos2) {
    $newstring = substr($text, 0, $stringpos2);
}  }
```

Not pretty, but hey it seems to work ^^. Anyway maybe someone of you have a better solution.

Comment: What about false positives, where you might have (say) `Mycoplasm` in the phrase, and nowhere the actual word `My`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using `explode`

```
$string = explode(" ", "My longest text to test");
$key = array_search("My", $string);
echo $string[$key] , " " , $string[$key + 1] ;
```

You can take i to the next level using case insensitive with `preg_match_all`

```
$string = "My longest text to test in my school that is very close to mY village" ;
var_dump(__search("My",$string));
```

Output

```
array
  0 => string 'My longest' (length=10)
  1 => string 'my school' (length=9)
  2 => string 'mY village' (length=10)
```

Function used

```
 function __search($search,$string)
 {
    $result = array();
    preg_match_all('/' . preg_quote($search) . '\s+\w+/i', $string, $result);
    return $result[0]; 
 }
```

Comment: Yes, this works but the big problem with the array solution is that you cannot search e.g. `my school`. Then you do not get a matching key, so this only works with single words in that way. But thank you for your idea.

Comment: hello baba thx for your idea. I tried your code, but it only works for the whole word. I think the only way to deal with, is using string functions. But since now i have not the 100% solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

An easy method would be to split it on whitespace and grab the current array index plus the next one:

```
// Word to search for:
$findme = "text";

// Using preg_split() to split on any amount of whitespace
// lowercasing the words, to make the search case-insensitive
$words = preg_split('/\s+/', "My longest text to test");

// Find the word in the array with array_search()
// calling strtolower() with array_map() to search case-insensitively
$idx = array_search(strtolower($findme), array_map('strtolower', $words));

if ($idx !== FALSE) {
  // If found, print the word and the following word from the array
  // as long as the following one exists.
  echo $words[$idx];
  if (isset($words[$idx + 1])) {
    echo " " . $words[$idx + 1];
  }
}

// Prints:
// "text to"
```

Comment: same as Baba this only works with a complete word and not parts of it. I think searching through an array will not work here or not this way.

Answer (score 2):

There are simpler ways to do that. String functions are useful if you don't want to look for something specific, but cut out a pre-defined length of something. Else use a regular expression:

```
 preg_match('/My\s+\w+/', $string, $result);

 print $result[0];
```

Here the `My` looks for the literal first word. And `\s+` for some spaces. While `\w+` matches word characters.

This adds some new syntax to learn. But less brittle than workarounds and lengthier string function code to accomplish the same.

Comment: i know that sometimes preg_match is the better solution but i have my problems to understand it ^^, even tough ive read some sites about it. Where is the searched input?